# Crystal Reports - Error in temp_{}.rtp file on client side

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# application running on the client side, that uses the Crystal Reports for generating and printing reports and billings of sorts using a local database.

The problem is, after installing a version, the program started returning the error "error in tmp_XXX..._{XXXX...}.rtp. Failed to retrieve from Database".
Thing is, an older version of the applications was working properly.

What I have tried:

- Installing the same version on my machine and another developer machine. It worked fine on both
- Tested running a Select, Insert, Alter and Update command using the application, both on client and developer machine. It worked fine on both cases
- Tested the Oracle connection with another program, namely MySQL Workbench. The connection was succesfully
- Reinstall the CR13SP27MSI32_0-10010309 (SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework x32)
- Install the CR13SP27MSI64_0-10010309 (SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework x64)
- Reinstall the application
- Wipe clean the temp folder(C:/users/.../temp)

Client side information:

- Windows 11
- No .Net Framework found on "Alter and Remove Programs". (Not sure if relevant)

I am out of ideas on what more to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hitting my head on the wall(figuratively, of course), I notice that the client did not have administrator permission to run the MSI files.

All that I needed was to do was the following:

1. Open the CMD as Administrator(Somehow, the client could use the CMD as Administrator, but not the MSI)
2. In the command prompt, input: msiexec /i "path\setup.msi"
3. Press Enter
4. Run the install as usual

Once done, all worked fine.

Comment: Great job.  The only issue I see is this would be difficult to deploy and instruct users on the installation.  I am facing the exact same issue.  Any thoughts on a script the users could more easily run?

Comment: You could create a .bat file to run it. It would only need an user with administrator privileges, the .bat file and the MSI. The .bat would be a single line, something like: msiexec /i "setup.msi" and the user only would need it to run it using "Run as Adminitrator".